# Split a .NET DataSet?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am working with a webservice that accepts a ADO.NET DataSet. The webservice will reject a submission if over 1000 rows are changed across all of the ten or so tables in the dataset.

I need to take my dataset and break it apart into chunks of less than 1000 changed rows. I can use DataSet.GetChanges() to produce a reduced dataset, but that still may exceed the changed row limit. Often a single table will have more than 1000 changes.

Right now, I think I need to: Create an empty copy of the dataset
Iterate over the DataTableCollection and `.Add` rows individually to the new tables until I get to the limit. Start a new dataset, and repeat until I've gone through everything.

Am I missing a simpler approach to this?

Comment: When copying records you'll lose the _changed_ status and details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is asking for trouble.  Often changes to one table are dependent on changes to another.  You don't want to split those up or bad things which may be difficult to debug problems will occur unless you are very very careful about this.  Most likely, the "right" thing to do here is to submit changes to the webservice on a more frequent basis instead of batching them up so much.

Comment: Good point. But in this case I can ensure that that the changes are handled in the correct order by the order that I go through the datatables.

Comment: It's not just about order.  Suppose your app submits changes for the first table but then crashes or maybe the PC gets unplugged or whatever before the other related tables are submitted.  Now you've got the database in a bad state.

Comment: Understood. But in this particular case, that would be fine. The code is only doing data additions, and the atomic level of a single row in a single table is fine, as long as order is followed. I entirely understand this may not always be the case but in this scenario, I'm fine.

Comment: DataAdapter will loop thru the DataSet to Update the changed rows underneath, so by breaking it you are not really doing any good. you are simply making nested loops and a chance of facing a problem or bugs are becoming much bigger. Unless you are not the owner of the WebService then avoid splitting the DataSet. Any way you can use Linq to split the DataSet if you must it will be faster than what you described